# Mac productbuild gives JavaScriptError

Tags: macos, pkgbuild, productbuild

I am trying to use the Mac `productbuild` app to make an installer for my application.

Running `productbuild` it does not throw any error but when I try to open the package it says:

```
There was an error reading the package: JavaScriptError.
```

When I tried to look at the installer logs, it says:

```
IFJS: **** exception SyntaxError: Expected Token "("
```

How I can debug/resolve this? Am I missing some file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue.

It was because of the special character used in Bundle identifier.

And, I was using this id as `choice` id in my `distribution.xml`

I was using `+` sign. Instead, when I used `Plus`, it worked!

Comment: Watch out for the "space" character too.

Comment: strangely, if you synthesize the distribution file using productbuild it will create invalid characters like this.

Comment: In one case productbuild is failing silently for me; product-output-path simply gets no file, and there's no message in console or the pipe to suggest what's wrong with my input.  All I see is "authexec[19609]: executing /usr/bin/productbuild" and then nothing.  In other cases (with obviously correct input!) it works fine.  Is there any way to get more info, like a hidden -verbose flag?  Thanks.

Comment: I think error messages are automatically directed to stderr. You can redirect it to a file through command line argument.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have said that I do get error messages in some cases, but in this one failing case there are none.

Comment: May be you can ask a separate question in SO by explaining what you are doing in some more detail, for ex, whether you are using a distribution file, all the arguments to the productbuild etc..